# Why is this onclick event not working on Android and iPhone?

Tags: android, ajax, mobile-safari, prototypejs

I am using Prototype JavaScript library for creating dynamic drop-down menus. Before the page loads, there is no event attached to the select statements with id, `id_bran` and `id_gen`.  As can be seen, the `init_image` is called when the page loads, and the `onclick` event is attached to those select statement.

This works fine in desktops where I can use a mouse to execute the click event. It however does not work in my Android and iPhone browsers. When the page loads, the `init_image` is called and the `getval` function is executed. Later however, when I make a selection in the dropdown menu, the `onclick` event does not call the `getval` function. So I am confident that the prototype library is working on my Android and iPhone as the ajax request is made on page load but it fails subsequently. What's going wrong here?

```
<!--
   MY HTML body->onload
   The init_image is called the first time when the page is loaded
-->
<body onLoad="init_image();">


//Javscript function called on page load
function init_image() {
    getval();
    //Assigning the event to id_gen and id_bran for mouse clicks
    document.getElementById("id_gen").onclick = getsize;
    document.getElementById("id_bran").onclick = getsize;
};


//Javascript function called on page load and during mouse click on the select 
//statement with id = id_bran and id_gen
function getval() {
     ur = 'szv/c1--'+$F('id_bran')+'/g1--'+$F('id_gen');
     new Ajax.Request(ur,
     {
         method:'get',
         onSuccess: function(transport){
           var response = transport.responseText;
           $('id_val').replace(response);
         }
      });
    };
```

Comment: ..make sure your js is wrapped in <script> tags

Comment: Looks like there is no getsize function defined here also

Comment: You could also try http://zeptojs.com/ instead of Prototype

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're force-injecting events and the load event which may lead to potential cross-browser issues. If you're using prototype.js, rely on it's native methods which are cross-browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {

 .. your code here ..
});
</script>
```

Then again for properly localizing and observing the click events, instead of:

```
document.getElementById("id_gen").onclick = getsize;
```

Use something like:

```
$('id_gen').on('click', getsize(e).bindAsEventListener(this));  // for prototype 1.7 branch
```

Or:

```
$('id_gen').observe('click', getsize(e).bindAsEventListener(this)); // for prototype 1.6 branch
```

Also by setting passing the `e` variable there, your `getsize()` function will have the Event object there, so you could stop it's native behaviour (like leading to #):

```
function getsize(e) {

    e.stop();
    .. your code here ..
}
```

Additionally, it would be best and much less bloated if you lock your whole logic into class and create an object for it... but that's a whole different story... :)

prototype.js is a **powerfull** tool, but needs some care.
I would suggest you reading some basics on the framework and following the API documentation later on:

http://prototypejs.org/learn/

http://api.prototypejs.org/